# calendar date selector not displaying date in capture mode

Tags: org-capture

I am having trouble with inserting dates in Capture mode.

The problem: I invoke Capture mode (`C-c c` for me). I type my task `** TODO some task`. I invoke calendar to schedule `C-c C-s`. I pick a date and hit return.

Strangely, the usual `SCHEDULED: [date]` doesn't appear below the TODO item. When I save and close Capture mode, the entry is filed *with the chosen date*. So, the date is being recorded properly. The odd thing is that it doesn't display properly in the Capture buffer.

Anyone else seen such behavior? Any suggestions on how to fix?

GNU Emacs 26.3, Org mode v 9.3

Comment: In your capture buffer press "C-h k C-c s" and report back what it says. My default for org-schedule is C-c C-s.  The keys C-h k are bound to 'describe-key. To get an idea of what it does press "C-h i d m emacs" (open emacs info) and then "i describe-key" (look for describe-key in the index).

Comment: @RichieHH sorry, I had a typo that I've corrected. I indeed use `C-c C-s` to invoke calendar for scheduling.

Comment: I was seeing this too. I think commit `5fc950a494` fixed the issue.